# Finding a SQL Server Database

Tags: sql-server

where do I find a database that has this connection string (it's not appearing in my local sql server list yet does exist as a sample app I'm using is creating data in it)

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDb)\v11.0;
```

Answer (score 0):

LocalDB is a tool for .NET developers to develop datbases without the overhead of setting up sql server. You can view information about the LocalDb instances using the utility SqlLocalDb.exe found here http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh212961.aspx

Comment: I have sql server 2012 on my pc already but it can't see the .mdf in question and doing a full search of the file system doesn't bring it back yet the MCV app is talking to it

Comment: Is AttachDbFilename in the connection string?

Comment: Yes - the full string is <add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDb)\v11.0;Initial Catalog=aspnet-appdb;Integrated Security=SSPI;AttachDBFilename=|DataDirectory|\appdb.mdf" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />

Comment: It looks like it is attaching a physical file when it connects so you should look for that file (appdb.mdf).

Comment: Try typing at a visual studio prompt sqllocaldb i aspnet-appdb

Comment: I did search for appdb.mdf on my entire c drive (only drive on my pc) and it's not there. Will continue along with the demo but thanks for the help - I was more curious